# html doesn't allow us to select alternate lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the alternate rows from the textarea
but in the current html, it doesn't allow us to select alternate lines.
I want to enter the text in the textbox like

**aaaaaaaaaa**

**bbbbbbbbb**

**ccccccccccc**

They can enter this in textarea.

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(){
 alert($('#txtData').val());
})
```

They will select lines containing 'aaaaaaaaaa' and 'cccccccccc'
and backend should get these 2 lines.[image]

i have a created a fiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/sain_anky/tr5v3z4e/)

Comment: show relevant html

Comment: where's your code ??

Comment: I don't think HTML textarea allows for multiselection. You probably should rethink why you're trying to do this and find a different way for this functionality.

Comment: is there any other library which allows us to enter the text in them in multiline and allow us to select the alternate line

Comment: You can use input fields stacked on top of each and styling to make them appear as one textarea. Otherwise you cannot do this with html alone

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not a jsfiddle. [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead. In any case, HTML does not allow selection of *anything* because that's not what HTML does!

Answer (score 0):

There only one way to doing so is use a list of input text boxes instead of a textarea. Because textarea contain all the text in element which can't be selected alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

Diffrent approach would be to use `contenteditable` attribute. You could use a `p` tag. Style them the way you want to appear like an input field etc... This attribute makes any element to be editable. For each row, you could add a `p` tag and select the one you need.

```html
<div>
  <p id="one" contenteditable="true">Line 1</p>
  <p id="two" contenteditable="true">Line 2</p>
  <p id="three" contenteditable="true">Line 3</p>
</div>
```